# Error 401 on ExecuteQuery SharePoint 2013 production SharePoint Server

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, permissions, solution

I create a farm solution that query in a list of SharePoint 2013.

When I run my solution in a development server using `Context.Credentials = new NetworkCredential('user', 'pass', 'domain')`, the query worked normally.

I add and active my solution in my production SharePoint Server, when I run the query into SharePoint Server, return erro 401.. My class of query:

```
public class Campanhas
{   
    public ListItemCollection GetItemsListCampanha(string CAML)
    {            
        using (ClientContext contextCallCenter = new ClientContext("http://SharePointSite/subsite/subsite/"))
        {
            contextCallCenter.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("login", "password", "domain");
            List ListCampanha = contextCallCenter.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("List Name");
            contextCallCenter.ExecuteQuery();
            CamlQuery queryCallCenter = new CamlQuery();
            queryCallCenter.ViewXml = CAML;
            ListItemCollection ListItemCampanha = ListCampanha.GetItems(queryCallCenter);

            contextCallCenter.Load(ListItemCampanha);
            contextCallCenter.ExecuteQuery();

            return ListItemCampanha;
        }
    }
}
```

Update: In Consolle Aplication not return error.

Comment: Why are you using the client object model in a farm solution?

Comment: Because her access other sites on my sharepoint

Comment: Maybee clarify that in the question :)

Comment: By the way, other sites is no reason for using client object model. Different farms is though.

Comment: Really, in the dev Machine is in other farm, but the solution add in current farm...

Comment: Do you make this call against the same server that hosts the solution without any reverse-proxies being resolved as the domain name you call to?

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by NTLM Double Hop authentication. This is why you are getting it on the server and not on a another machine.

Use the server sdk. If you need to execute it as a specific user then try this:

```
        SPUser user = SPContext.Current.Web.EnsureUser("login");

        //this creates the site and web objects as the user.
        using(SPSite site = new SPSite(SITE_URL, user.UserToken))
        {
            using(SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(WEB_URL))
            {
                // get your list items here.
            }
        }
```

Comment: And...In a ConsoleApplication all ok, in solution not work...

Comment: Does the person you're trying to impersonate have at least Visitor(read) permissions on the web and list?

Comment: Not, this user have Full Controll

Answer (score 0):

This might be a classical LoopbackCheck 401, where the server blocks calls made to itself resolved with a host header other than FQDN or NetBIOS name unless the domain name is registered in `BackConnectionHostnames` key. See also Spencer Harbar's article [DisableLoopbackCheck & how it affects SharePoint](http://www.harbar.net/archive/2009/07/02/disableloopbackcheck-amp-sharepoint-what-every-admin-and-developer-should-know.aspx) and http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861.

Take a look at this script by Jeremy Jameson that will help you implement the change:

https://github.com/jeremy-jameson/Toolbox/blob/master/PowerShell/Add-BackConnectionHostNames.ps1